# Microsoft Bot Service - How do proactively message multiple people in 1 call - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, botframework, azure-bot-service

I'm trying to send the same proactive message to many users within my organization. We are working with a Microsoft Teams bot, built with JavaScript.

We're currently looping through the users, grabbing their conversation reference, then proactively messaging each user 1 at a time.

We are sending the same proactive message to these users, so I'm looking for a way to send this message to a list of users with 1 call

We're currently using the 'continueConversation' function to proactively message users

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, getting a conversation reference for everyone who has previously messaged your bot and looping through while sending a message to each is the currently accepted method of implementing proactive messaging to all users.

For reference, the [docs on proactive notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-proactive-message?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript) and the [javascript proactive bot sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/16.proactive-messages).